# Adding ReSharper options to context menu in Visual Studio

Tags: resharper

In Visual Studio 2005, my coworker can right click a tab and he has an option "Find in Solution Explorer". I know this is from ReSharper and I'm running ReSharper 5.1 - how do I enable this extra context menu? I also know about the Shift+Alt+L shortcut for the same command but want to add the context menu.

This is what I see when I right click on a tab. The picture below is when I right clicked on a .cs file.

[image]

EDIT: Typo in the title.

Comment: Wow. Hardly any views and no repsonses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tools > Customize... > Toolbars tab > tick Context Menus. Find Other Context Menus > Easy MDI Document Window. Commands tab > ReSharper > ReSharper_LocateInSolutionExplorerAction. Drag it into the menu. Click Close.

Comment: This still works in VS 2017 with R# 2018.3. The only thing I wanted to point out is that the R# command is ReSharper_LocateInSolutionOrAssemblyExplorer.

Thanks for this -- it's saved me a ton of time more than once!

Comment: I didn't see this option (Tools > Customize... > Toolbars tab > Context Menus) in vs 2019.  There's also the sync with active document solution explorer button now.